# Error checkbox no seleccionado FileUpload

Tags: java, checkbox, fileupload

Tengo un problema con unos *checkbox*, cuando no son seleccionados me saca un error el programa y cuando los marco **todos** el programa funciona correctamente.

Necesito que si uno no es seleccionado se convierta en *null*.

```
          FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
          ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
           List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
String nombre=items.get(1).getString();
String fechaparameter=items.get(2).getString();
String select=items.get(3).getString();
String checkbox1 = items.get(4).getName();
String checkbox2 = items.get(5).getName();
String checkbox3 = items.get(6).getName();
String checkbox4 = items.get(7).getName();
String checkbox5 = items.get(8).getName();
```

Comment: ¿Que error te marca Pablo? ¿que valor quieres sea null, las variables checkbox...?

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
 java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
 servlets.Procesa.doPost(Procesa.java:218)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: El problema es que si selecciono todos si que me coge los 5 datos pero como deje uno sin seleccionar me peta :(

Comment: Tienes definido un listener al realizar la selección @PabloLozano agrégalo por favor :-)

Comment: he editado el codigo arriba, echale un vistazo